# Загрузка файла в Android

Tags: android

Пытаюсь загрузить файл по кнопке в Android приложении. Ловлю ошибку. "Не смог загрузить, ошибка".

```
 public void DownloadButton() {
    download_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                ThinDownloadManager downloadManager = new ThinDownloadManager(5);
                Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(AppConfig.URL_PDF1.toString());
                Uri destination = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/doc.pdf");


                DownloadRequest downloadRequest = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
                        .setDestinationURI(destination)
                        .setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.LOW)
                        .setDownloadListener(dw);

                downloadManager.add(downloadRequest);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Нет соединения. Ошибка!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

com.thin.downloadmanager.DownloadStatusListener dw = new com.thin.downloadmanager.DownloadStatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadComplete(int id) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Загрузка завершена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadFailed(int id, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Не смог загрузить, ошибка!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(int id, long totalBytes, long downloadedBytes, int progress) {

    }
};
```

Разрешения в манифесте установлены.

```
  <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Эмулятор Nexus 5X. 28 Api. В чём проблема?

Comment: В логах должно быть написано. Ну и в наше время уже мало просто установить разрешения в манифесте. Нужно а) их запросить и получить, б) каждый раз проверять наличие.

Comment: В onDownloadFailed вам передается текст ошибки, который вы игнорируете. Проверьте его в первую очередь. Но согласен с предыдущим комментатором, скорее всего вы не запросили права на запись во внешнее хранилище

Answer (score 0):

Я только добавил строчку

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

в мой код и он заработал так, как я ожидал.

```
 public void DownloadButton() {
    download_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

                ThinDownloadManager downloadManager = new ThinDownloadManager(5);
                Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(AppConfig.URL_PDF1.toString());
                Uri destination = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/doc.pdf");
```